# How many ways there are to arrange a boolean $2\times5$ matrix such that there won't be two zeros one above the other

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> How many ways there are to arrange a boolean $2\times5$ matrix such that there won't be two zeros one above the other.

For example, this is not allowed

```
01110
01111
```

I can brute force it but it doesn't seem right, there are too many calculations to do, so I thought that this is the same as asking that there won't be any 1s one above the other, which is symmetry, so if I'll add that condition, then there are only 2 ways to arrange the matrix:

```
10101  01010
01010  10101
```

But dividing 2 by 2 (since it's the same condition twice) can't be the answer so could it be $2^{10}-1$?

Comment: How many possibilities are there for the first row? Then, given some choice for the first row, how many possibilities are there for the second row? (This will depend on the number of zeros in the first row).

Comment: An easier method: rather, how many choices do you have for each column?  It could have been $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.  Apply multiplication principle.

Comment: @rogerl isn't that a lot of calculations?

Comment: @JMoravitz That's pretty nice!

Comment: Feel free to "answer your own question" using my hint in the space provided below so as to clear the question from the queue of unanswered questions.

Comment: My comment was too late

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is $3^5$ since for each column there are three options:

```
1 0 1
0 1 1
```

Thanks JMoravitz.